# Why does the neural network stop training because of the gradient?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, nntool

I am training a neural network and it stopped training due to the gradient stopping condition. From what I can see the gradient 8.14e<sup>-0.6</sup> is larger than minimum gradient 1e<sup>-0.5</sup>, so why did it stop? Is it because the gradient wasn't improving so there was little point continuing?

I am very new to neural networks (and using MATLAB's nntool) so any help/explanation would be much appreciated.

[image: Neural Network Training Performance]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a neural network problem, it is a problem of understanding floating point representations:

8.14e-06 = 8.14×10^−6 = 0.00000814 < 0.00001 = 1.0x10^-5 = 1e-05